# How to use pretty-error within a sailsjs app?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

[pretty-error](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pretty-error) has to be set up like this:

```
require('pretty-error').start(function(){
  startTheApp();
});
```

As I don't now where sailsjs starts the app, I've tried this on `config/bootstrap.js`:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {
  require('pretty-error').start(cb)
}
```

but it's not working.

Any guideline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pretty-error` is very easy to use for simple node programs where you can wrap the entire thing in a callback, but a little trickier for bigger apps.  If you want fully `pretty-error` coverage in Sails v0.10, you can do the following:

First, in your root `app.js` file, wrap `sails.lift(rc('sails'))` like so:

```
require('pretty-error').start(function(){
    // Start server
    sails.lift(rc('sails'));
});
```

This will take care of errors outside of your controller code (e.g. errors in your `bootstrap.js`).

Second, in your `api/responses/500.js`, require `pretty-error` at the top, and then replace the line that says `sails.log.error(errorToLog);` with:

```
var pe = new PrettyError();
console.log(pe.render(errorsToDisplay[i].original ? errorsToDisplay[i].original : errorsToDisplay[i]));
```

This should take care of errors in your controllers and models.

Comment: Thanks!! that worked. Note: to make it work, I had to start the app with `node app` instead of `sails lift`

Comment: Interesting.  Worked for me with `sails lift` on v0.10-rc4.  But regardless, you can do everything with `node app.js` that you can with `sails lift`!